# Couldn't find module:alloy/controller/container for architecture:i386

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

Everybody.

Now I am building a simple titanium project using appcelerator studio.
I am a beginner in this scope(titanium).
So I have some problems.
First I can't use "Alloy.createcontroller()".
Anyway I can see the message after running my project in iOS simulator (iOS 9.1).
Please let me know the reason why.

Help me!

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error should only occur if you are missing this controller in app/controllers/container (case sensitive)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have another problem now. I have built the simple prototype. Of course it is the titanium app. But I cant run this in Xcode. When I run my prototype, I can see the error(cannot find app.js). Please let me know the reason why.  I dont know about it. Regards.

Comment: We have a problem currently for running the app from Xcode: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19818 Why do you want to run from Xcode?

Comment: Because I have to register the app in developer.applie.com and make the ipa file. Of course I made the ipa, but while I run this app in my iPhone, I can see the same error<cannot find app.js> after displayed logo screen.  Regards.

Comment: To create an IPA for either ad-hoc or app store you can use Appcelerator Studio or the CLI. No need to use Xcode there (though we will get that working again of course). See https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/platform/latest/#!/guide/Distributing_iOS_apps